# How do I check the values for each array if it's equal to what I retrieved from my database?

Tags: java, list

I have a `List<Integer>` with the values `(3,3,2,3,4)`. How can I check each of all the values from an array are equal to? For example, `int value = 3`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //check all the values from the array
}
```

Comment: You are retrieving a list from the DB? Is the return variable of type java.utils.List? there is a java.sql.List implementation as well so you have to mind that as well.

Comment: I'm retrieving a value from my db then i'll be adding it to an `arraylist`

Comment: I don't get the question. You have a already a list and then you're retrieving another one from Firebase? And you want to compare if they have the same elements?

Comment: First I'm retrieving a values from firebase then add it to a `list` then i want to check if all the values from my list are `less than or equal to` the `int value = 3`

Comment: Why is the question `How can I check if it's equal`

Comment: Sorry my english is so bad

Comment: @vizsatiz I edited my post help please how to check each values and make an `if condition`

Comment: `if (list.get(i) == value)`

Comment: Tried that already what I want is check all inside the array if my `value` is `3` then my array `(3,3,2,3,4)` it has `2` on it should put a `toast or error message`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` function exposed by the list.

```
 int value = ...;
    List<Integer> list = ....;
    if (list.contains(value))
        // do your stuff
    else
        // do else stuff
```

Comment: `contains` doesn't do what I want. What I want is to check all for each values in my `list`